# Choice between image_picker and camera plugin

Tags: mobile, dart, camera, flutter

I'm currently implementing a functionnality that use the camera. I first decided to go for the camera plugin and customize it myself and it work well except for videos which has a bug sometimes when I try to start it with the video_player plugin and I don't know how to fix it. I just saw a video treating of image_picker and it seems to be a lot easier to implement and also more reliable than my implementation of the camera. So I wonder which should I choose. Does the UI of the camera preview is customizable (button,  front camera ) and do we have to use the video_player plugin to render the video or is this a feature part of image_picker ?

Comment: It's an image picker, it won't be useful for video. You cannot record video through the image picker plugin.

Comment: There is a method called 'pickVideo' so I assumed that there is a way to record videos https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/image_picker/latest/image_picker/ImagePicker/pickVideo.html

Comment: Well, I didn't know about that method. You can always try it out, but I'll have you know, you cannot change the appearance for the image picker camera prompt. So if its the same call, then probably for video also you might not be able to change appearance.

Comment: Ok thanks, then I guess I will just stay with the camera_plugin and find a way to make it work properly with videos.